# pymongo - mongo document bson size of an array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to capture the array size(bson size in bytes) using pymongo. Below is the sample document structure,

[image]

I'm able to retrieve the entire document size using following code snippet,

```
for doc in src_db.src_coll.find({'customProperties':{ '$exists' : True }}).limit(2):
    print(len(bson.BSON.encode(doc)))
```

But I'm unable to calculate the size of each sub array, example code which is failing,

```
for doc in src_db.Quotes.find({'customProperties':{ '$exists' : True }}).limit(1):
    print('doc_size:'+str(len(bson.BSON.encode(doc))))
    doc_customProp =  doc["customProperties"]
    print('custom_prop_size:'+str(len(bson.BSON.encode(doc_customProp))))
```

Output with Error:

```
doc_size: 363953
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./document_stats.py", line 15, in <module>
    print('custom_prop_size:'+str(len(bson.BSON.encode(doc_customProp))))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/bson/__init__.py", line 976, in encode
    return cls(_dict_to_bson(document, check_keys, codec_options))
TypeError: encoder expected a mapping type but got: [[u'custValue', u'{"identifier":"","productId":["3"]}']]
```

Expected output:

```
doc_size: 363953
custom_prop_size: *****
```

Comment: `BSON.encode` only works with a "dict". You either process each item from the list, or extract the singular key to it's own dict. Note that the latter case includes the size of the key as well as the content. Your picture only shows "lists within lists", so it's unclear what the underlying structure is. You really should not post pictures when the actual text representation of the objects is far more descriptive. And what we are actually looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to limit what you get back from MongoDB by using projection like this:

```
src_db.Quotes.find({'customProperties':{ '$exists' : True }}, {"_id": 0, "customProperties": 1})
```

Then you can simply get the size of the entire document.

Comment: But if i have to do the same for different arrays in the same document then i have to make another database call to each array which is very resource intensive. So, i'm trying to get the entire document & compute the size on the arrays what i need.

Comment: That's certainly true. Have you tried the following (I'm really just guessing, no clue if it might work or not: `print('custom_prop_size:'+str(len(bson.BSON.encode(vars(doc_customProp)))))`)

Comment: no, it didn't... TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute